# How to remove hosting provider's access to my dedicated servers?

Tags: security

I am interested in renting and setting up a dedicated server, but I would like to keep privacy and security in mind. I would prefer that the hosting provider never have direct access to the operating system or the software running on the server itself.

What steps are taken to remove hosting provider access from a dedicated server?

Do I change the password of remote management software, such as IPMI, iLO, iDRAC, KVM, etc? Is that possible?

Do I change the password of root user?

How about when the server is running?

Are the disk(s) and ram vulnerable to physical attack?

Also, what about OOB (out of band) management and physically connecting to the server?

Comment: Pick a reputable hosting provider you trust. As the movie industry discovered, once a device is in someone else's hands, you're screwed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regarding a rented dedicated server, can I remove IPMI (or relevant software) access and OOB (out-of-band) access to the server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/1108548/regarding-a-rented-dedicated-server-can-i-remove-ipmi-or-relevant-software-ac)

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting provider provides you with the Internet connection for the server, so theoretically they would have the ability to monitor your data transfer, so you should make sure that you only communicate in encrypted form.

Furthermore, you could install the system fully encrypted, but you have to be aware that a fully encrypted system usually expects you to enter a password at startup. The root password should be set by yourself in any case, but it will be if you reinstall the system anyway.

The RAM is a volatile memory that loses its data shortly after the loss of power. In order to get to the data that you have in RAM, a very professional and high effort would have to be made. Why should someone have such a high interest in getting to your server or the data on it? In this case, you might want to think about the server location.

Your provider will always have physical access to the server as long as it is located there, so you should basically trust your provider. Protecting your data with encryption is still a good thing.

Every running service that is provided to the outside world and every port that is open are potential threats. You have to be aware of that. And the measures listed above and by you cannot protect you from that.

The crucial question: From where do you expect a greater danger? From your provider or from attacks from the Internet?

Comment: At the moment, I am concerned about the hosting provider. Any advice in that case? Do I change the password of remote management software, such as IPMI, iLO, iDRAC, KVM, etc? Is that possible? Also, what about OOB (out of band) management and physically connecting to the server?

Comment: I don't get why the question arose at all. Why shouldn't you change them? What could prevent you from doing that and what are possible consequences?

Answer (score 0):

The generally accepted simplification is:

> Whatever safeguards and encryption you built into your software, they will not protect you from a determined adversary that has full control over the hardware where your software is running.

My possibly naive impression is that hosting providers are not that *"determined adversary"* and your datacenter threats are realistically more along a datacenter technician accidentally unplugging the wrong cables then for them to attempt to access your server.

One solution to address that though: bring your own server hardware and rather than renting a dedicated server, select a reputable co-location provider. Get your own locked suite/cage/serverrack and ensure your physical security.

A different question to ask is how and why are even big companies still using cloud solutions, where they don't even have any control over the physical hardware, even for valuable and sensitive applications and data they need to keep secured? Don't they have similar or the same concerns you have?

Do they simply trust the hosting provider to keep the hardware secure and eventually their data and applications?

In essence yes, but there is nothing "simple" about that.

There are cost-benefit and risk analyses as well as risk management processes.

Generally those companies are taking technical measures to control the risks (or at least should doing everything) to ensure that even when an adversary takes control over the hardware it won't be easy or trivial to use that access, for example by implementing the use of (full-disk) encryption for storing data rest, transport encryption for all communication between systems and users, signatures and non-repudiation for transactions, no default passwords, strong (MFA) authentication, no logging of sensitive information to the console etc.
(The same applies for your dedicated server. As long as you rent it is yours and you have both the ability and responsibility to take your own measures against unauthorised access.)

Then they don't rely on software and encryption solutions alone for their risk management; they do their due diligence in selecting trusted parties to manage their hosting and make them sign strict contracts, with SLA's and penalty clauses to keep them honest.

Reputable providers generally have a third-party audit and verify their own staff and teams, their business and processes to verify if they actually deliver on what they promised and should be doing. And as a small customer maybe you can't, but large customers can request/oversee such audits and/or the resulting audit reports.