# Regarding a rented dedicated server, can I remove IPMI (or relevant software) access and OOB (out-of-band) access to the server?

Tags: security

I am trying to secure a rented, dedicated server as much as possible. In my research I found that the hosting provider is likely to have access via IPMI and OOB. Is there anyway to prevent this, or limit this?

Comment: Ask your provider how to limit access.  Perhaps they can firewall and limit access via some additional layers of firewalls, or authentication.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to prevent this, or limit this?

Set a password. Normally you can configure the IPMI from within the OS using `ipmitool`.

That said, if you don't trust the people providing you with the hardware and holding the physical server you can give up. They hold all the cards, and could theoretically have JTAG interface attached to your machine to effectively dump any and all secrets from memory. They can modify the firmware of the machine to whatever they want. They can likely modify disk content to whatever they want...

So if you're ever in a situation where this is a relevant attack vector, the answer is not to secure IPMI (do that anyway, but for other reasons: accidental exposure mitigation), but to host the machine in a trusted location.

Comment: OK! What about OOB access? I am unfamiliar with this protocol.

Comment: Out-of-Band access is not a protocol - it is catch-all term for ways to manage your system without relying on the installed operating system. IPMI is one way, add-on systems like Dell's iDrac and HP ILO are others. A serial console, or an USB cable for keyboard/mouse and a VGA/hdmi cable to KVM switch are others.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you rent the server it is yours and you have both the ability and responsibility to take your own measures against unauthorised access via configuring the OS.

Having full administrator level access to a server usually also allows you to reconfigure the OoB add-on cards. You can and probably should reset the credentials there. Also configure your OS so that when somebody plugs in a keyboard and monitor they will still need to enter credentials.

As a caution: you yourself may also need that out-of-band access to recover your system.  Completely removing it may be shooting yourself in the foot.

(There are enough people that have configured their host-based firewall in such a way that they locked themselves out. Other times your system may end up in a state that needs administrator intervention to recover from.)